# Is there a trayless external hard disk enclosure available?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

I use in my Server a trayless hard disk rack, something like this: http://www.raidsonic.de/en/pages/products/mobile-racks.php?we_objectID=4343

I wonder if there is trayless **external** hard drive enclosure available? I searched but nothing turned up so far.

Comment: I guess I searched with the wrong keywords, thanks for the product links to all of you, exactly those I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any that the drive goes inside like you're showing, but I have one of these and realy like it:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817707170

The drive just slots in "naked".

Actually, it looks like the company that makes the tray you described also has "docks", too: http://www.icydock.com

They've got some sweet looking multi-disk external enclosures there, as well as "docks" like the StarTech that I have.

Comment: I have one very similar to this and I love it. Mine taks 2.5" or 3.5" SATA's, its great for swapping drives in and out, especially if you need to do any data recovery work.

Comment: I have the Thermaltake BlacX version and it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

The [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/) is just such a device, though it also provides a RAID controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a visual search on Google Images, like this one:

http://images.google.de/images?q=trayless%20external%20hard%20drive%20enclosure&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&hl=de&tab=wi

Perhaps you are lucky and can spot a model which is the right one for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several companies that manufacture [hard drive cradles](http://blogean.com/blog/cool-gadgets/sata-hard-disk-drive-cradle) that you just plug a drive into directly.  The ones I have seen are single-drive only, so may not be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a [Thermaltake BlacX eSata](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A4HAFS). I use it for backups.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what interfaces you are looking to connect with, NewerTech has the Voyager line of External 2.5" & 3.5" Hard Drive Dock Solutions.  They have a range of interfaces from Firewire800/400, USB 2.0 and eSATA for connections to multiple types of machines. Click the link below to review NewerTech Voyager's options.

http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/NewerTech/Voyager/Hard_Drive_Dock